# Php Switch Statement not showing all the cases redirects and links

Tags: php, switch-statement

i am beginner in PHP. Please Help me to resolve my code error:
Here is the code

```
<?php
     $qry=" SELECT * FROM `allopathy_cosmetology`
           UNION 
            SELECT * FROM `ayurveda_allergy`
           UNION 
            SELECT * FROM `beauty`
           UNION 
            SELECT * FROM `sidha_ophtalmology`
           UNION 
            SELECT * FROM `traditional`
           ORDER BY `Created_Date` DESC ";
     $sql=db_query($qry);
     while($obj=db_fetch_object($sql)){
        switch ($obj->video_img . $obj->v_id) {

        case 1:
            $obj->link="page/allopathy/cometology.php?v_id=".$obj->v_id;
            $obj->img="video/allopathy/thumb/".$obj->video_img;
            break;
        case 2:
            $obj->link="page/allopathy/cometology.php?v_id=".$obj->v_id;
            $obj->img="video/ayurveda/thumb/".$obj->video_img;
            break;
        case 3:
            $obj->link="page/traditional/index.php?v_id=".$obj->v_id;
            $obj->img="video/beauty/thumb/".$obj->video_img;
            break;
        case 4:
            $obj->link="page/sidha/ophtalmology.php?v_id=".$obj->v_id;
            $obj->img="video/sidha/thumb/".$obj->video_img;
            break;
        case 5:
            $obj->link="page/traditional/index.php?v_id=".$obj->v_id;
            $obj->img="video/traditional/thumb/".$obj->video_img;
            break;
        default :
            $obj->link="#";
            $obj->img="#";
        }
        echo " 

        <li><a href='$obj->link'>
        <img width='100px' src='$obj->img' /> <br />
        $obj->subject<br />$obj->author</a><hr /></li>";
    }
    ?>
```

The problem is that, it is not redirecting correctly and also the image is not shoing correctly. Only the last case (CASE 5) is functioning correctly. No other cases from 1 to 4 will not print the Image and Link.

Comment: And what happens when you call case 1 to 4?

Comment: Check what is in `$obj->video_img` and `$obj->v_id` I am guessing the switch only works when `$obj->video_img` is empty as `$obj->video_img` concatenated with `$obj->v_id` is unlikely to ever be a simple 1,2,3,4,5 unless `$obj->video_img` is empty

Comment: can u help me to edit me the code.

Comment: Not really! I have no idea what you are actually trying to achieve.

Comment: Results will come from table except the image of CASE 1 to 4, but author, subject will print but no image and link will come except the last case.

Comment: You could try showing a sample of the rows returned by EACH of the unioned queries